# Write all .tex file names in a folder to file, each inside an identical wrapper

Tags: vim

I have a folder full of .tex files and I would like to write these file names to file, each inside an identical wrapper.

For example, let's say that I have a folder with three .tex files A.tex, B.tex, and C.tex, although the file names don't follow a simple pattern. These .tex files are tables and I would like to wrap them to get `\begin{table} \input{A.tex} \end{table}` and so on.

My first thought was that there could be a LaTeX solution, but looking around at TeX SE it seems that this may be better handled in a Vim (specifically the third answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/how-to-iterate-through-the-name-of-files-in-a-folder)). Or is this a task better handled by Perl or some other scripting language? (I have limited Perl knowledge, but this would motivate me to learn more). Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a Unix-like system or do we need to do this with Windows?

Comment: @Kevin -- Locally I use gVim on 64-bit Win 7, but I also use Vim on a remote Linux server, which is where I generate the .tex files. Either solution is great by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of filenames that do not contain newline characters, the issue can be
easily solved in Vim script:

```
:call append('.', map(split(glob('*.tex'), '\n'), '''\begin{table} \input{''.v:val.''} \end{table}'''))
```

or

```
:let fmt = '\begin{table} \input{%s} \end{table}'
:call append('.', map(split(glob('*.tex'), '\n'), 'printf(fmt, v:val)'))
```

The commands above uses the `glob()` function to collect the list of filenames
matching given wildcard.  Resulting set of filenames is represented as
a string containing paths separated with newline characters.  Using the
`split()` function, the string is broken down into list, which is processed by
the `map()` function to format filenames according to desired text template.
Then, strings from this list are inserted below the current line with the
`append()` function.

Another way of populating a list of filenames in a buffer is to insert output
of system directory-listing command through the `:read!` command,

```
:r!ls *.tex
```

In order to format the list as necessary, run

```
:'[,']s/.*/\\begin{table} \\input{&} \\end{table}/
```

immediately after executing the previous command.

Comment: @richardh:  Thank you!  Please, take a look at the update of the answer.  I have added description of another way for solving the issue based on interaction with host system's commands.

Comment: Wow. I prefer the second option. It is a little more transparent to me  (and teaches me some other new skills). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While vim scripting could handle this, its going to be much easier in Bash.

```
for file in *.tex; do
    echo "\\begin{table} \\input{$file} \\end{table}" >> tables.Tex
done
```

Now, this does assume that none of the file names have characters  that must be escaped for Tex; if they do you can either do it within vim (`:%s/find/repl/g`) or with shell replacement (`${file//find/repl}`).